# Git commit from within a Makefile

Tags: make, git

I have a Makefile for a Latex project I'm working on. Makefiles aren't my forte, but is there a way to do something like:

```
make git "My comment"
```

And have the makefile execute:

```
git commit -m "My comment"
git push origin master
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a variable and read it from within the Makefile. Example:

```
git:
    git commit -m "$m"
```

Then you can commit with: `make git m="My comment"`.

Answer (score 7):

You could call it like

```
make git-"My comment"
```

and write a pattern rule for `git-%`:

```
git-%: 
        git commit -m "$(@:git-%=%)"
        git push origin master
```